# Camera and video icons are not showing even though I have bootstrap referenced correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent hours trying to find what is wrong with my code bur can't seem to find out what is wrong ,The following line is supposed show icons of a camera and image but it does not show up in the web page:

```
<i class="fa fa-image"></i> or <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
```

This is the whole class home.blade.php :

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        </head>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                {{--Friend request--}}
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    @if ($available_req_count > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                            <strong>Your have pending friend request
                                <a href="{{ url('friends/viewReq') }}" class="alert-link">Please check</a>
                            </strong>.
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home','files' =>true]) !!}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Add a new status</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Write a new status</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="status-text" id="status-text"></textarea>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">

                                    <label for="file upload" class="custom-file-upload">

                                        <i class="fa fa-image"></i> or <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>

                                    </label>
                                    <input id="file-upload" name="status_image_upload" type="file"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6=">

                                    <button class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add status
                                    </button>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                    @foreach($top_15_posts as $status)
                        {!!
                        view('layouts.app-internal.user-status-layout',[
                         'status' => $status,
                         'user' => \App\Eloquent\User::find($status->user_id),
                         'comments' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(),
                          'comment_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->count(),
                          'like_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusLikes::where('status_id',$status->id)->count()

                         ])
                         !!}
                    @endforeach

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

[Screenshot of what I get back on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtouP.jpg)

[Screenshot of what it is supposed look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAkpn.jpg)

Comment: use  4.7 this is the latest version of fa fa  icons...the icons you are trying to use can be newly added ..

Comment: You need to add fontawesome in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the icon use that class you need to use inclue `fontawesome`. Add this in your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Comment: you're welcome, just ask if you find another problem :D

Answer (score 2):

fa-camera or fa-video-camera need font awesome extension..
You can add font awesome library to your file. Copy this link..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or you can see the way to use font-awesome at http://fontawesome.io/get-started/.

Answer (score 0):

Use font awesome css include in your file

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  />
```

You are using class `fa` so you need to have the font awesome css library